# Testing cron job through URL

Tags: php

I'm testing cron job in localhost by giving URL in browser. It fetches records from XML file and stores into database. When executing for 10 min getting "Internal Server Error". File contains 20000 records. Unable to trace the issue. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

In your php.ini ; make php log errors to a file or syslog, then you can get the actual error message.

[Documentation for the runtime confirguration](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php), see notably the "error_log" configuration directive.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the maximum execution time of your script. This however may not be a good idea if you have many requests and you're using apache. Here's the [manual](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.set-time-limit.php). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) to set the number of seconds a script is allowed to run. Setting it to zero will turn time limits off. At the top of your PHP script add :

```
set_time_limit(0)
```

That will avoid any timeouts.